# View Pager and Array adapter with dynamic items and notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to create a `ViewPager`, and `ArrayAdapter` with following structure:

1. There are X number of tabs in my pager, and Y number of elements in it.
2. Both X and Y are variable(as the names suggest).
3. When there is some action on the item Y, say on 5th tab, I want to call `notifyDataSetChanged` on it.

Question:

How do I preserve the tab number and the item number ?

Answer (score 2):

In viewpager we can get current page by

viewPager.currentPage(); it return integer value 
then for arrayadapter there is item click listeners